# Run Reader wrapped in HtmlT, producing Html ()

Tags: haskell, haskell-lucid

I'm using Lucid to generate code for a static site, writing code in the `HtmlT (Reader MyEnv)` monad to transparently pass around some configuration stored in `MyEnv`.

The framework I'm using encapsulates the transformation from `Html ()` to file output, so I'd like to write a function to transform `HtmlT (Reader MyEnv) ()` to `Html ()`; something like:

```
withEnv :: MyEnv -> HtmlT (Reader MyEnv) () -> Html ()
```

But I haven't yet come up with a simple way to implement this. Am I missing something fundamental, or is there a workaround?

Comment: You haven't come up with a simple way, but what way have you come up with? Show us the effort you have made and we can go from there.

Comment: `HtmlT (ReadMyEnv)` is not a complete type, your signature is incorrect. If you wanted `HtmlT ((->) MyEnv) a -> (->) MyEnv (Html a)`, that's called [`commuteHtmlT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid-Base.html#v:commuteHtmlT).

Comment: @MichaelLitchard good call, I honestly was pretty stuck and didn't think I had much worth posting. Will consider in the future though.

Comment: @HTNW Thanks, I fixed the signature. commuteHtmlT looks like exactly what I was looking for! Frustrating that I didn't find that after a good deal of searching

Comment: I guess the fundamental concept I had been missing is the commute*T family of functions.

Comment: @HTNW I think it's worth writing that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`commuteHtmlT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid-Base.html#v:commuteHtmlT):

```
commuteHtmlT :: HtmlT (Reader MyEnv) a -> Reader MyEnd (Html a)
runReader :: Reader a r -> a -> r

withEnv :: MyEnv -> HtmlT (Reader MyEnv) a -> Html a
withEnv e = ($ e) . runReader . commuteHtmlT
```